# How to interpret a string as Perl code and execute it without eval

Tags: perl

I understand that "string-eval" can be used for it. But I am looking for some alternative to achieve it without `eval`. Reason being "string-eval" fail the Perl critic and as per client policy I can not use it.

What are some alternative to do that without `eval`?

Here is what I am trying to do:

I am passing a dynamic generated code reference to a function. This function evaluates this code reference and assign the result to a variable.

Comment: If you can't eval as per client policy, trying to find something that does the same thing using some other construct doesn't sound like a good idea at all. Find another way of doing what it is you need to do.

Comment: Your best bet is to ask another question, explaining what you want to do and people will tell you how to do it without `eval`.

Comment: Have you tried writing the `eval` string to a seperate file and executing it (via `do`)?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - updated my answer in short with what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @rpg : It's still quite vague to be honest. Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: Evaluating dynamic code is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Show us what is in this *code ref* string that you want to compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coderefs do not need `eval` to run. Simply dereference a coderef to invoke it. This is explained in [perldoc perlref](http://p3rl.org/ref).

```
my $code = sub {
    my ($name) = @_;
    say "Hi, $name!";
};
$code->('rpg');
```

Answer (score 9):

Perl critic objects to string-eval because "interpreting a string as perl code and executing it" is generally a poor solution to any problem.

You can't work around it by just finding another function to do the same thing (well, you could, but that would be entirely missing the point).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is great, appreciate your prompt response. But quick way to resolve it can be done by daxim's reply.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub exec_code {
    my ($c) = @_;
    return &{$c};
}

my $coderef = sub {
    print "Hello, from sub";
};

exec_code($coderef);
```